# setTimeOut AFTER jQuery form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Here is the deal: I have a form, that takes quite some time to submit, because I'm waiting for some third party web services. So what I'm trying to achieve is, that after the submit button is clicked, it gets disabled, is assigned a special class and if it takes more than 5 seconds to submit the form, a notice is displayed.

I've came up with this:

```
$('#register_index_button').click(function(){
$(this).addClass('bt_button_loader');
$(this).val('Please wait');
$(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
$('#register_index_form').submit();

//it takes more than 5 seconds, display notice
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#notice').html('Still waiting ...');
}, 5000);
});
```

Everything works fine, except the timeout function. I guess after I submit the form with jQuery, everything else after that is ignored?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Did you try putting the `setTimeout` before the `submit`?

Comment: you must put the settimeout inside the event onsubmit of the form.

Comment: how is your form? does it have web service url? if yes, then it will try to reload another page which will be result of the web service call.

Comment: put $('#register_index_form').submit(); inside setTimeout function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try attaching an event handler on the form for the "submit" event.  Put the timeout event handler function.

(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/submit)

```
$('#register_index_form').on('submit', function(){
     setTimeout(function() {
         $('#notice').html('Still waiting ...');
     }, 5000);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should submit after your services get returned, I really don't see any code there that does that, and after you receive your service response, you submit your form.

```
$('#register_index_button').click(function(){
$(this).addClass('bt_button_loader');
$(this).val('Please wait');
$(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');


//it takes more than 5 seconds, display notice
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#notice').html('Still waiting ...');

}, 5000);
});
```

Place it when the service is retrieved, an ajax call, in complete method.

```
$('#register_index_form').submit();
```

Comment: Ok, probably I need to provide extra info:

I'm using Codeigniter to handle form submission. My form has only one field and the value of this field is posted to a controller, where formValidation happens. One of the form validation rules is a callback function, where I do a SOAP request and based on the SOAP response, the callback function returns true or false. This soap request takes a while to complete and in the mean time the user has to wait for the form validation outcome, before it gets redirected to another page.

So I would like to give the user a notice after a few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

As @gaemaf stated.

```
$('#register_index_button').click(function(){
   $(this).addClass('bt_button_loader');
   $(this).val('Please wait');
   $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
   $('#register_index_form').submit(
       //Nested inside of the submit to be executed when submit 
       setTimeout(function() {
           $('#notice').html('Still waiting ...');
       }, 5000);
   );
});
```

Another method would be to gather up all of the fields from the form and submit them using an Ajax submit.

That way you can create the 'Please wait' when the ajax is fired and have a confirmation that the form has been received and is being processed. So something like....

```
$('#register_index_form').submit(function(){
    var url = "path/to/your/script.php"; 
    // the script where you handle the form input.
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: $("#register_index_form").serialize(), 
        // Gets the forms elements and submits them 
        timeout: 10000
        // How long the Ajax will wait before considering the call to have failed
     })
     .done(function( data ) {
          //Do something ...        
     });
     return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
});
```